# SVG not getting class or tranform

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following code I am dividing different operations for creating a bar chart with several different functions. The problem is when the svg is created the transform and the class are not applied. When I check in the console I see the svg appended but with not with or height or transform applied. You can view source page and click on the js on the live demo [here](https://www.z1labs.com/). Thank you.

This is the function where I am attempting to create and append the svg.

```
function buildBarChart(parentID, sourceData) {

    const div = d3.select(parentID);

    const margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
    };

    // get width & height
    const { width, height } = getWidthandHeight(div, margin);

    // append svg & g elements
    let svg = appendToParent(div, 'svg', 'svgWrapper', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attribute assignment in `appendToParent` function isn't correct, the attribute syntax is:

```
.attr("attribute-name", value)
```

and not passing an object

```
.attr({"attribute-name": value, "another-attribute-name": anotherValue})
```

Your function become:

```
function appendToParent(parent, type, className, transformation) {
return parent.append(type)
    .attr("class", className)
    .attr("transform", transformation)
    });
}
```